# Align different texts in different spans to same line

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a table which gets some information from database. But data has different styles, for e.g. different font-sizes. Therefore they need to be in same line.

### HTML

```html
<div id="parent">
    <span id="first">first</span>
    <span id="second">second</span>
</div>
```

### CSS

```css
span { vertical-align: text-bottom; }
#first {
    font-size:200%;   
}

#second {
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

But these codes did not fix this problem. Here is an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BmbWr/92/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: baseline` for your spans:

```css
span { vertical-align: baseline; }
```

fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BmbWr/94/)

Comment: Or he could just remove 'vertical-align:' also, unless it's necessary.

Comment: @Adsy, you are right, because the default value for `vartical-align` is `baseline`

Answer (score 0):

You can't just put `%` it needs to have a value:

```
#first {
    font-size:0%;   
}
```

This answer is based on the code you used for your Fiddle.

Comment: also it's not the solution. I want them on the same line.

Comment: they are on the same line, are they not?

Answer (score 0):

You can add one of following css according to your requirment.

```
span { vertical-align: center;  }
span { vertical-align: baseline; }
```